# ローカルのHTMLファイルから<iframe>で外部サイトを呼び出す？

Tags: html

ローカルのHTMLファイルに、`<iframe>`にて外部サイトを指定し表示させる方法はございますでしょうか。
通常通りに開くとセキュリティでブロックされてしまいますので、
該当ファイルにのみ、ユーザーが明示的にセキュリティを指定する方法などがございましたら、
ご教示頂けましたら幸いです。

祖父のために、ワンクリックでアクセスできる、
ヤフーとWebメールと検索窓が１つに並んだページを作ろうとした次第です。

Comment: yahooはhttpレスポンスヘッダのx-frame-optionsにSAMEORIGINを付けて返すので、yahoo以外のサイトからブラウザでフレーム表示することはできません。お爺さん用にわざわざ小さい画面を用意するなんてナンセンスすぎると思いますが。。。何のためにそれが必要なんでしょうか？

Comment: 大きな3つのボタンが並んだページぐらいで良いのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ローカルファイルにある html に `iframe` で埋め込む」という前提が動かせないのであれば出来ないと言ってよいと思います。 どうしても例外にしたいのであればブラウザのアドオンとして作れば出来るかもしれません。

やり方を抜きにして様々なウェブサービスをひとつの画面に集約したいということであればウェブブラウザにこだわらずに [Rambox](https://rambox.app/) といったソフトウェアを導入するというのも手軽な方法です。

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>祖父のためのページ</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>祖父のためのページ</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="ここに対象ページ１のURL">対象ページ１</a></li>
<li><a href="ここに対象ページ２のURL">対象ページ２</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>検索</h2>
<form action="ここに検索ページのURL" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="検索ワード">
<input type="submit" value="検索">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

お試しください。